# PCM / WAVE to AAC Conversion in android

Tags: android, wav, aac

My application(**android 2.2 and later**) needs to convert raw **PCM** audio **recorded at 22kHz** to **AAC**- (22 kHz) format. But the [MediaCodec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html) API is only available in android **4.1+** .

Is there any way i can convert pcm to aac in **android 2.2** and later ?

Comment: You could build ffmpeg for Android and bundle it with your app.

Comment: does it support all versions? They have only mentioned target os such as honeycomb, ics and android master branch  on http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffmpeg4android/

Answer (score 1):

FFmpeg for Android is a good way to go. Makefiles are tested only on mentioned targets, it doesn't mean they will not work on Froyo (and I believe they will). It is just that I do not have resources to test every possible build scenario. What I currently support is already too much for my equipment.